# How to raise character limit in FQL Query?

Tags: 2010, fast-search, query

as stated in the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394606%28v=office.14%29.aspx), the maximum length of a FQL Query is set to 2048 characters (SharePoint 2010). Is there any way to raise this limit?

Comment: Same question as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061330/how-to-overcome-fast-search-char-limitation-2048 but without answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit is in fact between the QRProxy WCF service and the FAST QR Server, and the limit is due to the QRProxy using GET requests against the QR Server.

It's been a while since I did it, but if you reverse engineer the QRProxy service and switch from GET to POST you should be able to have as long queries as you want.

The question is if you're comfortable with switching out the QRProxy service with your homebrew, as it seems there won't be an official update on this.

The short and officially correct answer is that any single query is locked to at 2048 characters. Doing multiple queries and merging the result is your only option unless you go to the dark side :)

Answer (score 2):

According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394606%28v=office.14%29.aspx) article you posted it looks like it is hard limit.

Can you split long query into multiple smaller and merge results?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but you can configure the max query length up to 20480 characters in SP2013 + SP2016:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/jj262349(v=office.15)

```
PS C:\Users\james> $ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication
PS C:\Users\james> $ssa.MaxKeywordQueryTextLength = 20480
PS C:\Users\james> $ssa.Update()
```